# Trouble with HyperV. How to lauch both a virtual machine using Vmware and debug a windows phone application with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, vmware, hyper-v

I have some trouble with HyperV. Here is my problem.

I am developing an application for Windows Phone that do some requests to a Web Server. In my case the web server is a debian vmware virtual machine. And because of HyperV I cannot launch both vmware and the Windows Phone emulator on my computer.
I don't have any Windows Phone device.
Nobody has a solution to my problem on internet.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this guide
http://superuser.com/questions/511001/running-hyper-v-and-vmware-together

Comment: I already saw this guide. If I understand correctly this is a way on how to create a Windows 8 virtual machine and installing Windows Phone emulators without HyperV but this is not what I am looking for. Moreover, I don't have enough RAM on my laptop for this :).

Comment: you could use a remote  web service  and test them on one of these devices 
http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/remote-device-access-for-nokia-lumia.html#toc_Installingyoursoftware

Comment: Did you try this?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680365/Running-Windows-Phone-Emulator-within-VMware-Vir

Comment: Those links show you how to emulate Windows Phone emulator. I think this is one step for my answer. But after this how can I tell visual studio how to debug my application with the  emulator created before?

Comment: Can you just create a Hyper-v machine with the web server?

Comment: Do you mean create a Hyper-V machine under a Debian? I don't know but I don't think so since my virtual machine is a debian.